# Transforming a circle into an ellipse with an affine transformation

Tags: matrices, geometry, conic-sections, affine-geometry

I have to prove that an affine trasformation $H_a=\begin{bmatrix} A & t \\ 0^T & 1\end{bmatrix}$ transforms a circle $C=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & \frac{d}{2} \\ 0 & 1 & \frac{e}{2} \\ \frac{d}{2} & \frac{e}{2} & f\end{bmatrix}$ into an ellipse (so the matrix $C'=H_a^{-T}CH_a^{-1}$ represents an ellipse) and it cannot map the ellipse into a hyperbola. Is there a short way to prove it without computing all the products and the inverse matrices?

Thank you in advance

Comment: The conic section represented by $\mathbf x^TM\mathbf x$, where $M$ is a symmetric matrix, is an ellipse if the determinant of the upper-right $2\times2$ submatrix of $M$ is positive (and $\det M\ne0$ so that the conic section is non-degenerate). What does transforming by $H_a$ do to these determinants of $C$?

Comment: How can I study the sign of these determinants  without knowing the signs of the elements of $A$ and $t$? This is what I don't understand

Comment: Multiply it out in block form and see what you get. You’ll need to use a general property of determinants to complete the proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $H_a$ is nonsingular, then so is $A$ and $$H_a^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}A^{-1}&-A^{-1}\mathbf t\\0&1\end{bmatrix}.$$ Writing $C$ in block form and transforming it produces $$\begin{bmatrix}(A^{-1})^T&0\\-(A^{-1}\mathbf t)^T&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}I_2&\mathbf b\\\mathbf b^T&f\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}A^{-1}&-A^{-1}\mathbf t\\0&1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}(A^{-1})^TA^{-1}&\cdots\\\vdots&\ddots\end{bmatrix}.$$ $\det (A^{-1})^TA^{-1}=\frac1{(\det A)^2}\gt0$, therefore the transformed equation represents an ellipse.

Comment: So an affine transformation cannot turn an ellipse into an hyperbola because the upper-left submatrix of a hyperbola has a determinant less than zero and if we transform the ellipse we get the upper-left submatrix $(A^{-1})^{-T}CA^{-1}$ that has the determinant greater than 0, right?

Comment: @B.junior That’s it exactly.